# .NET MVC AngularJS routing :Back button displays blank screen

Tags: browser, asp.net-mvc-5, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I am working on project with complete SPA cycle.Coming to the point, my issue is when I am hitting the browser back button the engine displays a blank screen and page is trying to reload.

This issue only happens when I try to move around views of between different MVC controllers. But the browser back button works fine for same MVC controller.

MVC Controllers:

- **HomeController** back button to **HomeController**  -> Works Perfect
- **TestDataController** back button to **HomeController**  -> Works Perfect
- **HomeController** back button to **TestDataController**  -> **Blank Screen**
- **HomeController** Forward button to **TestDataController**  -> **Blank screen**
  -

JS:

```
  //// creating a App
var app = angular.module("shellApp", ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('search', search);
//Setting route config
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'Home/Home'
    }).
    when('/resume', {
        templateUrl: 'Home/Resume'
    }).
    when('/webgrid', {
        templateUrl: 'TestData/WebGrid',
        controller: 'search'
    }).
    when('/tablewithangular', {
        templateUrl: 'TestData/TableWithAngular',
        controller: 'search'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'Home/Home'
    });
}]);
```

CSHTML:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#/resume">Skills</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" ng-class="{ open : dd1 }" ng-init="dd1 = false" ng-click="dd1 = !dd1">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Working Examples <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#/webgrid">WebGrid</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#/tablewithangular">Table with ng-sorting and ng-pagination</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: .Net here is not relevant, can you write the controllers here, because this could be a differents errors related with the template cache or the controller. I suggest create a simple example.